# Cartthrob Subscriptions…

Tags: cartthrob, subscriptions

I notice Cartthrob has a message up on the site about putting Subscriptions on hold. But the site still has a Buy Now feature on the subscriptions page... Is Subscriptions up and running again?

I want to use Cartthrob for both shop, but very importantly annual subscriptions. Is this not possible currently? (It is a project that needs completed in Aug, so a bit of a rush)

There is no automatic billing or the likes, simple the user subscribes for a year, and is notified when the subscription expires. There will also be products for sale separate to this, hence why I am interested in using Cartthrob.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has implemented a site using CartThrob & Subscriptions, I'd suggest you find an alternative.  It's incredibly buggy and incomplete, and has caused us no end of headaches.